# Fast way to localize time in python for large dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have datetime objects as indices in a pandas dataframe that I would like to localize without using a for loop.  Here's the code: (data is the dataframe)

```
from pytz import timezone
utc = timezone('UTC')
utc_times = [utc.localize(entry) for entry in data.index]
cst_times = [entry.astimezone(timezone('US/Central')) for entry in utc_times]
data.index = cst_times
```

As the dataset grows, this gets slow.  Any ways to speed this up?

Comment: Either you have to iterate over the dataset, in which case this looks pretty efficient, or you can localize the time point by point as the dataset grows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your index is a `DateTimeIndex`, you should be able to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
times = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2018-04-26 11:00:00', periods=50000, freq='1h')
data = pd.DataFrame(index=times)
utc_times = data.index.tz_localize('UTC')
cst_times = utc_times.tz_convert('US/Central')
data.index = cst_times
```

This method is over 1000x faster for an index of 50,000 times. See below:

```
%% time
# Original method
utc_times = [utc.localize(entry) for entry in data.index]
cst_times = [entry.astimezone(timezone('US/Central')) for entry in utc_times]
data.index = cst_times

CPU times: user 1.28 s, sys: 38.2 ms, total: 1.32 s
Wall time: 1.49 s
```

--

```
%%time
# New method
utc_times = data.index.tz_localize('UTC')
cst_times = utc_times.tz_convert('US/Central')
data.index = cst_times

CPU times: user 354 µs, sys: 9 µs, total: 363 µs
Wall time: 389 µs
```